# How to create wireframe fade off effect like this?

Tags: render-layers, compositing-nodes, freestyle, wireframe

[image: aaaa]

Can this be done with freestyle lines alone? or do I have to render separate layers and do it in the compositor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Various aspects of a Freestyle Line Style can be given [modifiers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/parameter_editor/line_style/modifiers/alpha/index.html), including the Alpha of the stroke.

The modifiers available to Alpha include *Distance From Object*. (In this example, the blue empty):

[image]

Which, with settings like this:

[image]

Can get a result like this:

[image]

Comment: Original way to do it! Thanks Mister Best ; )

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Duplicate the object.
2. On the duplicated object, add *Wireframe Modifier*.
3. Assign *Vertex Groups* and select it in the *Wireframe Modifier*. Which allows you to control the weight of wireframe and create the fading effect. Please refer to [Blender Manual for the sample image](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html#id3).

In case of still image, I believe doing it in post-production would be much easier and efficient.